# Data is too big to render for Highcharts export server

Tags: javascript, svg, highcharts, phantomjs

I have phantomjs installed correctly (at least I hope so) and when I try to export charts to images, there is no problem. But as soon as I try to export huge file on export server (JSON to PNG) I get the following error:

> Timeout converting SVG, is your file this big, or maybe you have a syntax error in the javascript callback?

I tried changing timeouts in app-convert.properties as well as timeouts in config file (highcharts-convert.js) but with no luck. Even when I set huge timeouts, I get the very same error.

When I delete some data from series I get the image, which I wanted.

EDIT: i hopefuly fixed it, thanks guys. I realized that problem might be in tickInterval option, which i didnt set. I tried it with this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ntr6a44k/

```
tickInterval: null
```

as well as copying this data to export server and run into the issue i wrote.

When i set tickInterval option to highcharts like in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zoyuurtd/ ,

```
tickInterval: 1500
```

chart get painted as well as exported.

Thanks for all answers.

Comment: And when you try to Highcahrts exporting server do you encounter the same issue?

Comment: Yes, i get the very same error. Tried it here : http://export.highcharts.com/

Comment: So could you recreate issue on jsFiddle? Maybe there indeed is to many data and you need to set much higher timeout?

Comment: You may want to look into the upload data size. For Tomcat you can set it like this: http://www.netroby.com/view.php?id=3585#.VBA7DvldXQg.

Comment: i updated answer, hopefully i fixed it. I will see tommorow myself, when my export server goes live again. Thanks for all answers